# Windows 8 in GPT not hybrid booting

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, boot, gpt, hybrid-boot

Some days ago I bought a new HDD of 3TB size.
I installed Windows 8 "normally", then I noticed that the system could not see all the 3TB of the disk, because the setup automatically choosed to use MBR boot sector. So I converted to GPT and extended the partition to 3TB. Then I noticed that the boot has become slower (like when it isn't hybrid booting), even if I have flagged the "Turn on fast startup" checkbox on Control Panel.

Is there a way to verify that my impression is correct?

Comment: You need a 3T disk in 1 chunk for the OS partition? Being a speed freak, that would just be all wrong to me. You can have files splattered all over the whole 3T , which would not be as efficent as having a first "Short-Stroke" partition for the OS, and seperate partition (or parititons) for all the data one could store on such a large disk.  If your worried about the speed, the whole strategy could be adjusted first, which could make larger gains, which may be sufficent to solution the whole.

Comment: @Psycogeek
You're probably right when you say that my decision of having just one large partition isn't the best, anyway, I can't split it into more partitions, because the limitation (in MBR) of a maximum of 2TB is at "disk level". So (for example), I'm not able to split it into two 1.5 TB partitions.

Comment: @codroipo - What?  What did you do exactly to convert it?

Comment: @Ramhound That's what I did. I use GPT partition, but then I noticed that the boot became slower and I asked if is there a way to verify this impression.

Comment: If you have hybrid boot enable there is no way just converting it to GPT would make it slower.  Something else is going on.

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry, I noticed your edit after I answered.
I converted the partition using AOMEI Partition Assistant

Comment: Can you post a picture of your disk within disk manager.  A link to an image within a comment is fine

Comment: @Ramhound
http://s3.postimg.org/agmfharoj/disk_State.png
http://s4.postimg.org/dui5vc77h/disk_State1.png
"Integro" means "Healthy"
"Avvio" means "Boot"
Please tell me if other sentences are not comprehensible

Comment: That isn't what I asked for :$

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry, what do you mean with disk manager?

Comment: The utility is literally called "Disk Management"

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, my picture comes from "Disk Management", I don't know what you meant with "a picture of your disk within disk manager", can you explain it to me so i can post the correct picture?

Comment: I was suggesting to make the partitions with the disk and partitions as the GPT you already changed it to. . GPT addresses the larger disks for booting, it does not restrict you from partitioning it. it does not restrict you to larger than 2G disks. You can part it up similar to how you would part up a mbr based one.